# /usr/lib/libwrap.7.dylib Error after install mac osx 10.8

Tags: macos, git, ssh

I have problem with using git after upgrading to MAC OSX 10.8.2.
Trace shows that there is a missing lib file:

```
git push
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libwrap.7.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ssh
Reason: image not found
```

which cause SSH to fail and then GIT since git use SSH.
Google around see ton of kind of similiar problem, but non seem to provide a working solution.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, unlink then reinstall your app. e.g. if you use Homebrew:

```
brew unlink git
brew install git --build-from-source
```

(Edit: I also ran `brew install libtool --universal` before the above. That may have also done it.)